# How to recover lost sol files in remix Safari 14.1.2

Tags: remix

I was using remix IDE in safari a few weeks before. But today when I open remix and all my sol files in `default_workspace` disappeared. It seems that remix reset itself back to factory default. I am not award of any cleaning data or cache on the Safari browser. Tried to migrate but there is nothing to migrate. The sol files shall be somewhere on local drive. There is no more info I can provide other than the sol files disappeared in remix without reason. Please help if you can. Many thanks.

Comment: Found key:value pair for remix.etherum.org in delelop=>show js console. The value seems to be hash output. how to decipher the value and convert it into plain text?

Comment: Try asking in their github repo for help, https://github.com/ethereum/remix-project.